# TortoiseSVN Commit failed with github

Tags: github, tortoisesvn

Hi I keep on getting this error when I add a new folder with a .txt file inside the folder.

Error: Commit failed (details follow):
Error: File 'C:\wamp\www\repo\trunk\test\test.txt' is out of date
Error: Invalid PROPPATCH property
Error: You have to update your working copy first.

I have updated my repo and the text file is not empty, I have added some text to it.

The funny part is if I create a file on github and update my repo I edit the file and commit it back and it works. But when I create a new Folder or text file and try to commit that I get the error above. before I commit I also add the Files first then commit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using TortoiseSVN (a Subversion client) with GitHub instead of a Git client like [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/)? (I know [it's possible](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/), but I'm not sure that I'd recommend it.)

Comment: Hi no i just decided to use it Its verry simple